# How to fix java.io.IOException: Attempted read from closed stream?

Tags: java, ioexception, rest-assured

I have below code which throwing IO error at second print statement. I am not able to figure out why it is throwing. Can any one help me out. If I comment that line working fine. What I understood is I am using the response object two times  but I should be able to use more than one time.

```
Response response=customerResource.customerOperations("post",
    MDFCommonUtil.getInstance()
    .readFileAsString("CommonFiles/payloadForPost.xml"),null);

System.out.println("inside the methid=="+response.getStatusCode());
    
System.out.println("inside the methid=="+response.asString());
```

Stack trace:

```
 java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream.     at
 org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.isReadAllowed(EofSensorInputStream.java:110)
     at
 org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:136)
     at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)     at
 sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)     at
 sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)     at
 java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)     at
 java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)     at
 java.io.BufferedReader.read1(Unknown Source)     at
 java.io.BufferedReader.read(Unknown Source)     at
 java.io.Reader.read(Unknown Source)     at
 java_io_Reader$read.call(Unknown Source)     at
 com.jayway.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseImpl.convertStreamToString(RestAssuredResponseImpl.groovy:366)
     at
 com.jayway.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseImpl.this$2$convertStreamToString(RestAssuredResponseImpl.groovy)
     at
 com.jayway.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseImpl$this$2$convertStreamToString.callCurrent(Unknown
 Source)     at
 com.jayway.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseImpl.asString(RestAssuredResponseImpl.groovy:144)
     at
 mdf.test.rest.testcases.TestCustomerResource.postCustomerFeature2(TestCustomerResource.java:60)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)     at
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
 org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)     at
 org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)     at
 org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)     at
 org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
     at
 org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)     at
 org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)     at
 org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)     at
 org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)     at
 org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)     at
 org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)     at
 org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)     at
 org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)     at
 org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)     at
 org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)     at
 org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)     at
 org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)     at
 org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)     at
 org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

Comment: possible you have closed the response before asString() is called

Comment: Please show your exception stack trace.

Comment: readFileAsString() already closed the file

Comment: Stack traces should be posted ***in the question.*** You can see for yourself that they're illegibile in comments.

Comment: J.Rush Nowhere I closed the stream

Comment: I am having same kind of problem but in my code, I am providing multiple download file functionality, but when user click on multiple files to download and if any one file is not available than we show message, but instead it is throwing exception. My Code is in Groovy but I am getting IOException and Error message is not displayed to user
Though I am using this statement [response.outputStream.flush()] to flush stream when file is available and download screen is shown otherwise I want to show error to user which is not shown and instead Socket Reset is shown as exception... Any Help???